# adding a exception rule to do not disturb?

Tags: notifications, do-not-disturb

I talk to a quite a few Americans, I my self am English, they message me during the night but, I do not want to switch off notifications for that Skype chat, otherwise as always, I will forget to switch it back on, and will miss something...

Can kind-of rules be added to the do not disturb?

or is do not disturb do not disturb at all regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The only exceptions to Do Not Disturb are calls or texts from individual contacts that you have marked with Emergency Bypass. (Edit a contact, tap on Ringtone or Text tone, then enable Emergency Bypass at the top of the screen. You have to do this for each of calls [ringtone] and texts [text tone] if you want both to get through.)

You cannot add exceptions for any other kind of notifications or activities.